# Simple steps to re-signing an iOS app?

Tags: ios, air, code-signing, enterprise-distribution

I’m trying to understand how to re-sign an IOS app (an .ipa file ). I’ve created this app for a client who now wants to be able to distribute using its own Apple Enterprise Distribution credentials.

I’ve developed the app with Adobe’s AIR for iOS packager on Windows (using Flash CS5.5 and FlashDevelop).  I’ve got a perfectly functional iOS app which also distributes well, over the air, using my own Apple Developers credentials.

I also have possession of my client’s Enterprise Distribution certificate, password and provisioning profile.

I’m not sure if I can create an ‘in house’ distribution using these credential with my Windows tools. I’ve been led to believe that I must ‘re-sign’ this app on a Mac, but I’ve seen only confusing descriptions of how to do this.

Does anyone know a simple set of steps that I can follow, using Xcode, Codesign, or anything else to re-issue this app as an Enterprise distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found my answer: re-signing is not necessary. The Enterprise distribution is done, easily, inside of Flash, running on Windows, using proper Enterprise Developer's credentials **and** the 'ad-hoc' type of distribution.